# cURL command - Neo4j

Tags: curl, neo4j

I have a problem in using of cURL as HTTP client with Neo4j.
When I write this command : `curl http://localhost:7474/db/data/` (or any URL, like `http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/`) *Then* I get this result in JSON format:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "No authorization token supplied.",
      "code": "Neo.ClientError.Security.AuthorizationFailed"
    }
  ],
  "authentication": "http://localhost:7474/authentication"
}
```

Answer (score 7):

It seems that you have the authentication plugin enabled on your server.
https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/authentication-extension

You should try something of the form

```
curl --user username:password http://localhost:7474/db/data/
```

Answer (score 4):

Disagreeing with @hydraruiz, I guess you're running a Neo4j 2.2.0-M0x version. This one has authentication enabled by default. You first need to acquire a token by providing your username and password.

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"username":"neo4j", "password":"mypassword"}' http://localhost:7474/authentication
{
  "username" : "neo4j",
  "password_change" : "http://localhost:7474/user/neo4j/password",
  "password_change_required" : false,
  "authorization_token" : "53eaa48a972439012868a8d5463e0c3d",
  "authorization_token_change" : "http://localhost:7474/user/neo4j/authorization_token"
}
```

Subsequent calls to the REST API use the token in the Authorization header. According to the docs the value of the http Authorization header is `Basic realm="Neo4j"` plus the base64 encoded token prefixed by a colon. We can use command line tools for this: `echo -n ":tokenstring" | base64`. For simplicity I emit a trivial cypher statement `match (n) return count(n)`:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Basic realm=\"Neo4j\" `echo -n ":53eaa48a972439012868a8d5463e0c3d" | base64`" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d '{"statements":[{"statement":"match (n) return count(n)"}]}' \
    http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit
```

returns:

```
{"results":[{"columns":["count(n)"],"data":[{"row":[0]}]}],"errors":[]}
```

That means the authentication worked.

Answer (score 2):

You can also [disable authorization](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.2.0/security-server.html#security-server-auth). In `conf/neo4j-server.properties` file:

```
# Require (or disable the requirement of) auth to access Neo4j
dbms.security.auth_enabled=false
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Neo4j Community 4.4.7 (probably with earlier versions, too), here are two ways you can authenticate against Neo4j using `curl`. The first way (using `--user`) is easy to find examples of, but the second way (using "Authorization" header) wasn't clear how to construct

For both of these examples, assume the following:

- username = "neo4j"
- password = "am4zeftw"
- IP address of Neo4j is `11.22.33.44`
- port is `7474`

Also, the examples don't specify an actual query, they're both using "`...`" as dummy text since it isn't relevant to the examples.

**1. `--user` parameter**

Specify username and password as command-line input using `--user` flag, which would look like this: `--user neo4j:am4zeftw` and the entire command looks like this:

```
curl --user neo4j:am4zeftw \
-X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' \
http://11.22.33.44:7474/db/data/transaction/commit -d "..."
```

**2. "Authorization" header**

This has a few steps:

1. In order to authenticate this way, you first need to construct a base64 encoding of the username and password combination. If you structure a string in the correct format – "user:password" – and then run that into `base64` you'll get a correctly formatted string. The example below generates `bmVvNGo6YW00emVmdHc=`:

   ```
   echo -n 'neo4j:am4zeftw' | base64
   bmVvNGo6YW00emVmdHc=
   ```
2. Instead of using this:

   - `--user neo4j:am4zeftw`

   use this:

   - `-H 'Authorization:Basic bmVvNGo6YW00emVmdHc='` (where `bmVvNGo6YW00emVmdHc=` came from the `base64` step above)

   As an alternative, you can specify `--header` instead of `-H`.

   Here's an example:

   ```
   curl -H 'Authorization:Basic bmVvNGo6YW00emVmdHc=' \
   -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' \
   http://11.22.33.44:7474/db/data/transaction/commit -d "..."
   ```