# API REST with CYPHER request

Tags: curl, neo4j

When I execute this command :

```
curl -X POST

 -H "Content-Type:application/json" 

 -d '{\"statements\" : [ 

 {\"statement\" : \"MATCH n OPTIONAL MATCH n-[r]-m

   DELETE n,r\"} ]}' 

 http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit
```

I get this result :

---

```
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
curl: (3) [globbing] illegal character in range specification at pos 2
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host '"MATCH'
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'n'
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'OPTIONAL'
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'MATCH'
curl: (3) [globbing] error: bad range specification after pos 4
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'DELETE'
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket at pos 5
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket at pos 1
{"results":[],"errors":[]}
```

---

Why I get this problem ? knowing that I have a neo4j database ...

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the whole thing on one single line or use a backslash at the end of each line. See [my reply on a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27824356/158701) regarding cURL and Neo4j.

Comment: Yes, I already put this command on one single line : `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json"  -d '{\"statements\" : [{\"statement\" : \"MATCH n OPTIONAL MATCH n-[r]-m DELETE n,r\"} ]}' http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit` and I get always the same problem

Comment: try to omit the backslashes before the double quotes.

Comment: I used this : `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json"  -d '{"statements" : [{"statement" : "MATCH n OPTIONAL MATCH n-[r]-m DELETE n,r"} ]}' http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit` and I get this result :  curl: (7) couldn't connect to host   
curl: (3) [globbing] illegal character in range specification at pos 2   
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host    
curl: (3) [globbing] error: bad range specification after pos 27   
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket at pos 1  
{"results":[],"errors":[]  }

Answer (score 0):

You can try in this way:

```
    data='{
        "statements": [
            {
                "statement": "MATCH n OPTIONAL MATCH n-[r]-m DELETE n,r"
            }
        ]
      }'

curl -X POST 'http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit'  \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-d "$data"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -X POST -H accept:application/json \
-H content-type:application/json \
-H Authorization:"Basic <your auth>" \
http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit \
-d "{\"statements\": [{\"statement\": \"MATCH n OPTIONAL MATCH n-[r]-m DELETE n,r\"}]}"
```

This one works great; covers auth, query, and accept content.